# MIgrating from Flex 3.1 to 3.5

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I want to migrate from Flex 3.1 to Flex 3.5, but I can't find any useful release notes on the differences between the two. I found the official Adobe website but it is more focused on the difference between 2 and 3, and not different versions of 3. Can someone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Forget about 3.5! 4.5 is already here.

Comment: @zdmytriv 4.5 isn't exactly here; but there are pre-release versions available. For production apps, I wouldn't go beyond 4.1 .  Moving from Flex 3 to Flex 4 is more of a chore than Flex 3 to 3.5

Answer (score 2):

In theory there isn't a lot of difference.  Have you tried to just change the SDK on your project(s) and then see what works or doesn't?

Msot of the issues you'll run into, I expect, will relate to your custom component development that extend the existing components.  The Flextras AutoCompleteComboBox, for example, had issues because the way the drop down is handled in the Flex ComboBox changed from 3.4 to 3.5.  Since our component is a highly customized ComboBox; we inherited this change which "Broke".

However, my experience is probably a fringe case as in the course of normal development you wouldn't be customizing things so heavily.

Try it and see.